# How can I change Finder's default font size system wide?

Tags: macos, mac, fonts, finder, imac

I am using an iMac 5k with 27 inch screen. The screen is great. The problem is the screen is too large which makes the font looks smaller in Finder.

Command+J can only change the view option for one folder, is there any way to change the font size to 14 system wide?

I am using El Capitan public beta right now, but I think this problem applies to almost all versions of OSX.

Thanks.

Comment: There has to be a "Use as Defaults" Button in the View Options panel.

Comment: Yes, but I want to change view options for all folders, not just one